# Oh my zsh theme color not showing as in screenshots

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh, hyper

I'm using zsh with ohmyzsh in windows 10 with Hyper (using ubuntu bash). But when I use the "ls" command the colors of the output are horrible. Nothing similar to the screenshots of the theme I'm using "af-magic". Why is that happening? How could I change those colors?

[Here's a screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De049.png)

Look at that, I can't even see the folders names with that horrible yellow background. I read something about changing something called "LS_COLORS", but being honest I didn't understand what I read.

Comment: Depending on how you specify colors, `zsh` isn't actually telling the terminal emulator to make this text, e.g, green, but rather, make it color number 3 in your palette. The terminal can be configured to use any color you want for color number 3. (Some terminals do support escape sequences that specify colors directly, rather than indirectly through a palette, but again, that's a terminal-specific feature.)

Comment: ¡Thank you! I will then find how to customize those colors in my terminal instead of looking how to change them in zsh.

Comment: @BernardoAyala : See [here](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors) for an easy-to-read tutorial on how to configure _LS_COLORS_.